# Can anyone enlight on why scrollspy and jquery are not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on portfolio project via freeCodeCamp and I'm stuck with 2 problems that I failed to fix so far.

1) I want to use Scrollspy (I discovered it on w3c) to automatically update links in a navigation list based on scroll position. I followed the tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) and tried to understand the exemple, but I can't find what is wrong with my code. It's not working.

2) Considering my first problem, I have been thinking that maybe my problem comes from adding attribute to the body (it's the first time I try to use body element in codepen as from the tutorial I assumed codepen includes it automatically).

So I had the idea to use jQuery to add attributes to the body element. But it appears that jQuery is not working. I tried to use the basic code from FCC lesson, like making a button bounce, but nothing happens.

(I think I have integrated bootstrap library and added jQuery.js via codepen settings so I can't find what's the problem here).

Here is my work in progress if you have a few minutes to check the code: https://codepen.io/pqdeguingand/full/gvgjPG

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <img src="http://stickersign.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive navbar-brand">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#presentation">Présentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#realisations">Réalisations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="presentation" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Nous sommes Sticker Sign</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="realisations" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Réalisations</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Contactez-nous</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope you can help me figure this out, Google failed for now!

Thanks a lot

Comment: add bootstrap.min.js to your code

Answer (score 0):

Please add this jQuery code in our template. So, when you click on menu item them scroll smoothly on there relevant sections.

```
$(document).ready( function(){  
 $(".navbar-nav a, .captions a").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   }, 2000);
 });
```

});

Comment: Thanks I did it, it looks good. Will be perfect when scrollspy is working